# How can I log the current progress of a ASP.net core 3.1 MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, logging

There are currently 3 people working on a ASP.net core MVC (without EF) project which one of them is an Admin. I want to log the changes that's been made in the current project they are working on in an .JSON file or .txt.  How can I do this and how can I see who has changed what and when in the ASP.net core 3 MVC project.

I want to implement this logging system in ASP.net core MVC 3.1 c#.

Comment: Use source control like github

Comment: @PankajRawat This is exactly what I was searching for, thanks brother.

Comment: yesterday, GitHub announce free unlimited private repo https://analyticsindiamag.com/github-is-making-private-repositories-free-for-teams/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about file changes? There's no way to do that, per se. You can utilize a source control system like Git, and when the devs commit their changes, you'll be able generate diffs and see exactly what was changed where and when, but that's only after the changes have been committed. You can't monitor what they're doing in realtime, without installing spyware on their machines. (Note: That's not a recommendation, just in case it's not clear that that was a joke.)

Comment: I was searching for a source control system. Thank you!